# Aplicar middlewrae a una ruta LARAVEL

Tags: laravel-5

quisiera saber como puedo aplicar un middleware a una ruta especifica en **Laravel 5.6**, lo que pretendo es que solo usuarios logeados puedan acceder a la ruta.

```
Route::get('https://josearandav.github.io/Tea-Docs/docs/', function () {
    return view();
})->middleware('auth');
```

El acceso a esta ruta esta en un botón de un menú.
Gracias por su ayuda masters!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas del modo siguiente:

1. Crea la ruta del siguiente modo, apuntando a un método dentro de un controlador

   `Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@login');`
2. Posterior en un supuesto Método llamado login dentro del Controller AdminController, haz lo siguiente

declara el siguiente método

```
public function __construct() 
{
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Y posteriormente declara el método login

```
public function login()
{
   return view('login');
}
```

Como ya queremos proteger la ruta lo hacemos del modo siguiente

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@login')->middleware('auth');
```